# Can I install visual c++ 2010 express edition with visual Studio 2010 professional already installed?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, installation, visual-c++-2010

I want to do so because intellisense option for clr console application is not working in visual studio 2010..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no Intellisense support for C++/CLI in Visual Studio 2010 (including in SP1 and the Express edition).

I've been using [Visual Assist X from Whole Tomato](http://www.wholetomato.com/) software for the last few weeks and am very happy with their Intellisense support. From the research I did, it appears that theirs is about the best going (Resharper for example does not support C++).

Comment: The Express editions don't support plugins so you'll need the Professional edition for this to work.

Comment: C++/CLI doesn't have Intellisense. C++ in general does.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can. They will run side by side.

However, if you have professional installed, wouldn't it be better to update the install and add c++ to it?

Answer (score 2):

No, this is not going to solve your problem.  The IntelliSense parser is exactly the same in the Express edition, it also doesn't support parsing C++/CLI code.  You'll need to find the installer for the VS2008 Express edition.  That's going to be quite difficult, you cannot get it from Microsoft anymore.  Or you'll have to bear and grin it until the next version for Visual Studio, the Microsoft team promised it will be supported again.

Do keep in mind that you are *not* writing C++ code, C++/CLI is a very distinct language.  There isn't much point in writing complete console mode apps in C++/CLI, you might as well use C#.  There's an Express edition for that as well, IntelliSense works.

Comment: @harish: Hmm, I think [this link](http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/en-us/products/2008-editions/express) still works to download VS 2008 Express from Microsoft. That's definitely your best bet if you really want to write C++/CLI code. Otherwise, switch to C#. There's generally little point in writing C++/CLI other than for interop purposes.